# create a dictionary with map from SCALA

Tags: scala, dictionary, maps, jena

Good day everyone, 
I am trying to create a dictionary from one RDF file using apache Jena, after I create the model, I take each statement and divide the file by subject, predicate and object, then I assign a number to each unique URI, blank node and literal, 
but when I create the map, appear an error about the map has too many argument, I don't understand why, someone can help me?
The code is the following:

```
  var x:Int=0
  val dictionary:scala.collection.immutable.Map[Node, Int]
  // read the RDF/XML file
  model.read(in, null)
  val iter:StmtIterator = model.listStatements()

  // print out the predicate, subject and object of each statement
  def print {
    while (iter.hasNext) {
      {
        x+=1
        val stmt: Statement = iter.nextStatement
        val subject: Node = stmt.getSubject.asNode()
        dictionary(subject,x)
        x+=1
        val predicate: Node = stmt.getPredicate.asNode()
        dictionary(predicate,x)
        x+=1
        val obj: Node = stmt.getObject.asNode()
        dictionary(obj,x)

      }
    }
    for ((k,v) <- dictionary) printf("key: %s, value: %s\n", k, v)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an immutable (unchangeable) Map.

```
val dictionary:scala.collection.immutable.Map[Node, Int]
```

The `apply()` method for all Maps is the element retrieval method and it takes only one argument (the key).

```
dictionary(obj,x)  <-- too many args, can't retrieve element from Map
```

What you can do is use a mutable Map...

```
val dictionary: collection.mutable.Map[Node, Int]()
```

...and then update/insert it like so.

```
dictionary += (obj -> x)
```